# 'ng' is not recognized as a command in Hyper terminal

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal, angular-cli

I have installed angular cli. It's working fine in NodeJS terminal, but not in Hyper terminal. I tried reinstalling both Hyper and the angular cli, but it didn't work.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ealmh.png)

Comment: I'm guessing that something is missing from your path or your path hasn't been reloaded. What happens if you type `path` at the command prompt? Does it then work if you try again?

Comment: Yes, its working.

Comment: So it's all fixed now?

Comment: No, the path command works. ng is not.

Comment: Not sure how you installed angular cli, I'm assuming npm or yarn but do you see any mention of node, npm or yarn in the output from `path`?

Comment: Yes, npm folder is in there.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you've installed angular correctly:
C:\Users\YourUser\npm install -g @angular/cli

Don't forget the -g I did and I found that problem too.